# how to change the caption for buttons used in image_cropper?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an application with `image_cropper`, flutter package.  It has two buttons, `cancel` and `done`. I want to set the caption for these buttons in Japanese.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I rewrite my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. After a good review of the docs, I found the options, `doneButtonTitle` and `cancelButtonTitle`.